# adding an alert dialog box with a retry button

Tags: android

I am working on a project where an alert dialog box appears if there is no internet connection on the phone.
This alert dialog box says that Network is Unavailable and has a button "Retry" where the user retry the internet connection test.

How can i implement this button correctly ? is there a "goto" statement so it can repeat if there is no internet connection ? i tried the labeled break and continue it didn't work.

This is my code:

```
if(isNetworkAvailable())
    {
        GetBlogPostsTask getBlogPostsTask = new GetBlogPostsTask();
        getBlogPostsTask.execute();
    }
    else
        {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("ERROR !!");
            builder.setMessage("Sorry there was an error getting data from the Internet.\nNetwork Unavailable!");
;
            builder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {

                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network Unavailable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

Comment: You could implement a recursive method.

Comment: and how can i do that ? can you show me please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just one example, you should implement AlertDialog as global variable for not creating one every time you try to make the request.

```
public void runTask () {
    if(isNetworkAvailable())
    {
        GetBlogPostsTask getBlogPostsTask = new GetBlogPostsTask();
        getBlogPostsTask.execute();
    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("ERROR !!");
        builder.setMessage("Sorry there was an error getting data from the Internet.\nNetwork Unavailable!");
        ;

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        builder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                runTask();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network Unavailable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @TeRRo no need to change the answer, its covered in "DialogInterface dialog" while ooverriding the onCLick() method

Answer (score 6):

There is a small error in **TeRRo**'s Code.
You are calling `AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();` before adding Buttons so buttons are not adding up.

So I updated the code. This code will check for internet connection if internet is available, it executes whatever you want, if not, It displays Alert Dialog with two buttons.

**Updated code:**

```
    if(isNetworkAvailable()) {

    /* DO WHATEVER YOU WANT IF INTERNET IS AVAILABLE */

    } else {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(false);
        builder.setTitle("No Internet");
        builder.setMessage("Internet is required. Please Retry.");

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.dismiss();
                finish();
            }
        });

        builder.setPositiveButton("Retry", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                InitiateDownload();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create(); // calling builder.create after adding buttons
        dialog.show();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Network Unavailable!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

**isNetworkAvailable() is a Helper method to determine if Internet connection is available.**

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

**Note:** `builder.setCancelable(false);` - so user won't able to dismiss dialog by pressing back button. Happy coding.