# i can't dismiss the custom dialog

Tags: android, dialog, customdialog

i'm trying to create a custom dialog with one `button` (**TRY AGAIN**)
this dialog testing if there is a internet connection or not. when user clicks (**TRY AGAIN**) button and if there is no internet connection custom dialog will showing again , and when there is internet connection dialog will dismissed

```
 private void showDialog() {
        myDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        myDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        assert myDialog.getWindow() != null;
        myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);
        text.setText(getResources().getText(R.string.nointernent));
        myDialog.setCancelable(false);
        Button tyragain = myDialog.findViewById(R.id.tryagainbtn);
        tyragain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              if (!isNetworkConnected()) {
                    showDialog();
                }
                else{
                    myDialog.dismiss();

                }
            }
        });

        myDialog.show();
}
```

/**/

```
public  boolean isNetworkConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager connectionManager = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectionManager == null) {
        return false;
    }
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (networkInfo == null) {
        return false;
    }
    return networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: networkInfo.isConnected() is returning true?

Comment: @android_Muncher yes isNetworkConnected method works fine

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: this is repeating but that is not the issue .myDialog.setCancelable(false);

Comment: @android_Muncher i remove it and still the same problem when i click on TRY AGAIN button dialgo won't dismiss

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526981/adding-an-alert-dialog-box-with-a-retry-button

Comment: @vilpe89 when i click try again and with internet connection dialog won't dismiss

Comment: What do you have in refreshContent method?

Comment: @vilpe89 with or without the refreshContent method dialog still won't dismiss :(

Comment: What if you only leave that `myDialog.dismiss();` line in there

Comment: @vilpe89 Unfortunately still doesn't work this really strange problem

Comment: `myDialog` is assigned a new `Dialog` every time `showDialog()` is called, so the instances are likely getting mixed up. Keep that variable local - `final Dialog myDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());` - and remove the class field.

Comment: @MikeM. your right when i click th TRY AGAIN button for example ( 5 clicks ) and there is no internet connection dialog showing 5 times, so when the internet back i should click 5 times to dismiss dialog , please if there any way to dismiss all dialogs

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm following you, but if you're going to show the `Dialog` again, you still want to dismiss the current one, so `myDialog.dismiss();` should not be in an `else`. That is, `if (!isNetworkConnected()) { showDialog(); } myDialog.dismiss();`.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks so much ,for your comments Simply i want to show custom dialog when there is no internet connection this dialog contains one button when internet back and i click try again dialog will dismiss

Comment: @G.Dator yes that's what i need , but my problem when i click the try again button and isNetworkConnected is false ( there is no internet connection ) my dialog showing to this point is good when internet is back and when i click TRY again dialog won't dismiss

Comment: OK, then if you want the `Dialog` to dismiss and pop-up again immediately, then what I show above should do it. If you'd rather just not dismiss the `Dialog` until the network is connected, then only call `myDialog.dismiss()` if `isNetworkConnected()` is true, and remove the `showDialog()` call from `onClick()` altogether.

Comment: when you're calling your showDialog? I think there you'll solve your problem because if you know that `isNetworkConnected` is `true` you wouldn't show your dialog at that time.

Comment: @MikeM. if i do that when `isNetworkConnected` is false and i click **TRY AGAIN** dialog will dismiss This is what I don't want for that i put `Showdialog()`  again in`onClick()`

Comment: If you don't dismiss the current `Dialog` when you call `showDialog()` again, you will have two `Dialog`s showing.

Answer (score 0):

finally i solved my problem by added `myDialog.isShowing()`

```
if (!isNetworkConnected() && myDialog.isShowing()) {
                    showDialog();

                }
                else{
                    myDialog.dismiss();
                    refreshContent();
                }
```